# Localization and Lists of Decimal Numbers

Tags: localization

I'm working on localizing some strings in our application and we have text that looks something like:

```
Factor f (1.0, 1.2, or 1.5)
```

In a locale that uses a comma for the decimal point, would this be written as:

```
Factor f (1,0, 1,2, or 1,5)
```

Maybe it's just not what I'm accustomed to, but that looks crazy hard to read quickly.

I'm also wondering about text like version numbers. Would Firefox 3.5.1 be Firefox 3,5,1?

Comment: What technology (as in programming language, framework, whatever)?

Comment: Version numbers are not localizable. Usually, even application names stay completely in English.

Comment: @Paweł I don't think the technology is relevant, is it? I was just hoping that somebody from a country that uses a comma for the decimal separator could tell me how they write lists of numbers. This text would end up in the UI or perhaps in a printed report.

Comment: Sorry I thought you are looking for formatting code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for, there are two things in regards to Internationalization here:

- Decimal separator
- List separator

Obviously these separators are quite tightly coupled, so in Locale that uses comma as decimal separator, list separator must be something else. Usually this is a semicolon and there just a few Locales that uses something different than comma or semicolon for list separator.

To summarize:

In Locales that uses **dot** as a decimal separator, **comma** is usually used as a list separator, so in some free-form text you might expect something like `Factor f (1.0, 1.2, or 1.5)`.
In Locales that uses **comma** as a decimal separator, **semicolon** is typically used as a list separator – `Faktor f (1,0; 1,2; oder 1,5)` is something you should expect.

I am not sure what you are up to (the technology does matter in the advice) but you can leave the format as well as list separator to the translators to decide. In .Net list separator is given, though (no need to ask translators for input, just use appropriate property of `CultureInfo` class).

Comment: Thank you! After reading this I went and looked through the regional settings in Windows 7 and found that indeed they do have a list separator entry. I was using Spain as an example and their list separator is a semi-colon, exactly as you suggested.

Comment: _"Obviously these separators are quite tightly coupled, so in Locale that uses comma as decimal separator, list separator must be something else."_ But there are cultures where both are same (f.e. `es-AR`, Spanish - Argentina). I just wanted to point that out, in case someone thinks that it's always a different one. It can cause conflicts, for example with CSV files. You can use this query to find all conflicting cultures: `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Where(c => c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == c.TextInfo.ListSeparator)`

Comment: Note there are other list separators as well, such as Ethiopic comma and Arabic comma (which are also provided by .NET CultureInfo). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/,

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but I don't know about your first question. However, as far as version numbers go, they are generally left *untranslated*. End users typically attribute little meaning to the version's *numeric value* (they are infact NOT numeric in nature. `3.90` < `3.100`).  They are simply discrete numbers with a universally-accepted separator, and not natural numbers with natural "grouping/decimal" separators.

In addition to end-user experience with version numbers.  Developers are often known to parse version numbers in the standard format of `{major}.{minor}.{revision}`, using `.` as the well-known seperator character.

I did find [this link](http://www.xencraft.com/resources/multi-currency.html#list) that talks about your first question (*sort of*).  I don't know how authoritative or credible it is; but it doesn't look dubious.